# Does miner moss "dirtiness" have any relation to the amount of gold that can be expected?

Tags: gold-rush-the-game

Bit of a long question, but let me clear up the fuzz as best I can.

In Gold Rush : the Game, as part of the larger wash-plants, miner's moss is fitted to sluice-boxes towards the end of the recovery process. As the plant washes the pay-dirt, the gold collects in the miner's moss, amongst other places in the plant.

Now, I've noticed that, depending on the dirt that was loaded into the plant for washing, the miner's moss comes out in varying degrees of dirtiness (i.e. one set of 12 miner's moss is dirtier than another set of 12 miner's moss). To me, it would make sense that, the dirtier the moss, the better the gold is in clean up.

My question is this, does the dirtiness of the miner's moss have any relation to how much of gold you can be expecting from a clean up? Or is the dirtiness of moss mats purely cosmetic?